# fabric kill gunicorn process and restart

Tags: python, django, fabric, gunicorn

I am using fabric for site deployment which uses gunicorn.
I have following code which is called by `deploy()` function.

```
def restart_gunicorn():
    sudo('ps ax|grep gunicorn')
    sudo('pkill -HUP -f [g]unicorn.*master')
    sudo('gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8080 %(path)s/application/wsgi &' % env)
```

when I run my fab file it shows following:

```
    out:  7694 pts/18   S+     0:00 grep gunicorn
[127.0.0.1:2222] out: 

[127.0.0.1:2222] sudo: pkill -HUP -f [g]unicorn.*master
[127.0.0.1:2222] out: sudo password:
[127.0.0.1:2222] out: 

Fatal error: sudo() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!

Requested: pkill -HUP -f [g]unicorn.*master
```

I think it should kill gunicorn and restart it..
What I am missing here ??

Answer (score 5):

That is because your gunicorn process isn't named exactly as `gunicorn` and you maybe having more than one gunicorn process running (master and workers).

It is usually the master that you want to kill. It's very rarely that you want to kill it out right, more often you just want to reload your code so -HUP is sufficient. So try this:

```
sudo('pkill -HUP -f [g]unicorn.*master')
```

Based on your comments, it seems that most of your problems are due to Gunicorn not running on your system at all. There are two options, you can do a test before hand, or you can just use [warn_only](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/env.html)

```
with settings(warn_only=True):
    sudo('pkill -HUP -f [g]unicorn.*master')
    sudo('gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8080 %(path)s/application/wsgi &' % env)
```

Note that your sudo('ps ax|grep gunicorn') line isn't needed here.

Comment: out:  7694 pts/18   S+     0:00 grep gunicorn
[127.0.0.1:2222] out: 

[127.0.0.1:2222] sudo: pkill -HUP -f [g]unicorn.*master
[127.0.0.1:2222] out: sudo password:
[127.0.0.1:2222] out: 

Fatal error: sudo() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!

Requested: pkill -HUP -f [g]unicorn.*master

Comment: repeat: "update question with output of ps ax|grep gunicorn"

Comment: ANd where in the question have you added the output from ps -ax| grep gunicorn? I certainly don't see it anywhere. In case I am not getting through: Please login to your server. Type ps -ax| grep gunicorn, copy and output from that command, edit the question and paste it in there.

Comment: 7694 pts/18   S+     0:00 grep gunicorn is the output from ps ax|grep

Comment: 9368 pts/16   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto gunicorn
probably you are looking for this

Comment: I only want to kill the process if it is running.. How can I do that in fabric ?

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
sudo('reload gunicorn')
```